# "No match for operator=" trying to iterate through map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, compiler-errors, constants

I'm trying to iterate through a map defined as the following:

```
std::map< size_type, std::pair<size_t, unsigned int> > ridx_;
```

Now I'm trying to iterate through ridx_ (which is a private member of a class) in the following friend function which overloads operator<<

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const SMatrix &m) 
{
  std::map< size_type, std::pair<size_t, unsigned int> >::iterator it;

  //The following is line 34
  for (it = m.ridx_.begin(); it !=  m.ridx_.end(); it++)
    os << it->first << endl;

  return os;
}
```

However g++ errors out with:

> SMatrix.cpp:34: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'it =
>   m->SMatrix::ridx_.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::begin with
>   _Key = unsigned int, _Tp = std::pair,
>   _Compare = std::less, _Alloc =
>   std::allocator > >' /usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_tree.h:152: note:
>   candidates are: std::_Rb_tree_iterator > >&
>   std::_Rb_tree_iterator > >::operator=(const
>   std::_Rb_tree_iterator > >&) make: *** [myTest] Error 1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `m` (and therefore `m.ridx_`) is const, you must use the `std::map< size_type, std::pair<size_t, unsigned int> >::const_iterator`, not `::iterator` here.

If you're using a C++0x compiler, you might want to consider using `auto` as well:

```
for (auto it = m.ridx_.begin(); it != m.ridx_.end(); it++)
```

Comment: I dream of the day when the error messages are human readable by someone with less than alot of familiarity with c++.